# Javascript variable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do the following:

- On click I need to set a javascript variable
- I then to set the value of an input field that is on a PREVIOUS spot on the same page to the value of this variable I set.

This is my code for the button.

```
<button onclick="close_modal()">close</button>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function close_modal() {
        var userID = <?php echo 1; ?>;
        $('#modal-findAsset').modal('hide');   
    }
</script>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please also include your HTML. It's not clear what you mean by 'previous spot on the same page'

Comment: I just mean the input field is above the button

Comment: We still need to se your HTML to know what selector to use to retrieve the element.

Comment: So why can't you show it to us?

Comment: Assign an unique id to the relevant input field and get its contents: `$('#unique-input-id').val();`

Comment: something like <input id="random" type="text">

Comment: Why are you being so difficult? Please update your question and show how the two parts of the HTML relate. Is it right above it, is there a DIV around them, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

> I just mean the input field is above the button

If it's in the same parent element as the button, then the minimal-mod way to do it is:

```
<button onclick="close_modal(this)">close</button>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function close_modal(btn) {
        var variable = $(btn).prevAll("input").first().val();

        var userID = <?php echo 1; ?>;
        $('#modal-findAsset').modal('hide');   
    }
</script>
```

Note I'm passing `this` into `close_modal` as `btn` so that we have context, and then using `$(btn).prevAll("input").first().val()`, which does this:

- Gets a jQuery wrapper for the button
- Uses `prevAll` to find all previous *sibling* `input` elements (e.g., in the same parent)
- Uses `first` to take the one closest to the button
- Uses `val` to get the value

But there's probably a better way of structuring the HTML, and therefore the code, to make this less fragile.

For example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/pugesovo/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/pugesovo/1/edit))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="row">
      <label>A:
        <input type="text" value="a">
      </label>
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label>B:
        <input type="text" value="b">
      </label>
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div class="row">
    <div>
      <label>C:
        <input type="text" value="c">
      </label>
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    $("#container").on("click", "button", function() {
      // Get the input value related to this row
      alert($(this).closest(".row").find("input").val());
    });
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, the markup appropriate to what you're doing will probably not be just nested `div` elements (or maybe it would be), but...

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<button onclick="close_modal()">close</button>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function close_modal() {
        var userID = <?php echo 1; ?>;
        $('#modal-findAsset').modal('hide');
        $('#random').val(userID);//set input value here.   
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the HTML is like this:

```
<input type="text">
<button onclick="close_modal(this)">close</button>
```

Then the JS should be:

```
function close_modal(button) {
    var userID = <?php echo 1; ?>;
    $('#modal-findAsset').modal('hide');
    $(button).prev().val(userId);  
}
```